# C++ XE RAD2 exe filesize suddenly large

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, filesize, c++builder-xe2

I am working on a larger c++ program using embarcadero's RAD XE2.

Now I noticed, that the generated .exe-file (Release and Debug) suddenly got a lot larger!
Before, it was around 1.2Mb, now it's 4.0Mb!
I could understand it if I had added tons of new libraries or importet some Image-file, but all I did was adding some functions and variables...

Is there a behavior/option in the IDE that I switched wrong? 
Or some other reason why the filesize got so much bigger?

Comment: I find that XE5 sometimes adds `fmx.lib` to the static link list for no apparent reason (and the linker links the entire library), perhaps that is the same thing you are seeing.

Comment: I highly recommend using version control (e.g. `git`) ; then you can check history and see what changed in the project file.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks for the suggestion! how can I check to see whether it adds fmx.lib? I also used a differenz version-control: I added a comment with datestamp and a keyword on each line I changed. Then I can get an overview using notepad++ Search-in-all-files feature. However, as I said, nothing really changed... I added some io-operations (write arrays to text-files etc.), some math-operations, some commands to draw lines... not even used a new library^^

Comment: Check the `.cbproj` file for the string `.lib`.  You can edit this file to remove junk libraries if you're sure your project doesn't need them (close the project before doing this)

Comment: Another possibility is something went wrong with incremental link; you could try disabling incremental link and the PCH cache, and doing a Clean . Of course maybe you did actually make a change that uses a new library and you didn't realize :)

Comment: It is possible to turn on a Detailed Segment Map (I think it's in the Linker Options in Project Properties) , this does have the info you need to see where all the space is coming from, but it is hard work to read the map